# Trouble installing latest Vagrant

Tags: installation, software-center, vagrant

Thanks in advance for any help I can get. I'm on raring.

I require the latest Vagrant in a work project and have followed these steps:

1. $ apt-get install vagrant (installs 1.0.3)
2. Downloaded the latest debian package from http://downloads.vagrantup.com/
3. Running the package through the Software Center, fails with error: "Software can't be installed or removed because the authentication service is not available."
4. Attempted to run package through Software Center with sudo: Software Center crashes.

I also had a go at the ppa

Thanks again.

Comment: 3 years later - same problem. It installs 1.8.1, when the latest is 1.8.5. Shall we use Debian distr-s?

Answer (score 4):

You can install it as follows:

1. Download the relevant `.deb` file from the [Vagrant Downloads](http://downloads.vagrantup.com/) page depending on whether you are using a 32 bit or 64 bit installation of Ubuntu. For v1.3.3:

   - [vagrant_1.3.3_x86_64.deb](http://files.vagrantup.com/packages/db8e7a9c79b23264da129f55cf8569167fc22415/vagrant_1.3.3_x86_64.deb) (64 bit)
   - [vagrant_1.3.3_i686.deb](http://files.vagrantup.com/packages/db8e7a9c79b23264da129f55cf8569167fc22415/vagrant_1.3.3_i686.deb) (32 bit)
2. Install from the command line using:

   `sudo dpkg -i <filename>`

Comment: Which one is relevant? There are no Ubuntu version. (only MacOsX, Windows, Debian and Centos).

Comment: Debian file should work